# Troubleshooting MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: mysql, exception

I have a closed-source upgrade application which migrates my database from an old format to a new format (creates new tables and migrates data from the old to new tables).

The application crashes with a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. It doesn't give me the name of the table with the primary key violation or the contents of the broken SQL query.

Is there any MySQL server option that I can switch to give me more troubleshooting information? Maybe the text of the failed query or the name of the primary key constraint which is violated?

Comment: The error is generally due to a collision with either the primary key or a unique key constraint.  Do you have either setup on the table?

Comment: The database has a large number of tables most of which do have primary/unique constraints. My problem is determining which of the  constraints was violated.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the general log file: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html . This way it might be possible to see at which point the server stops processing the queries.

You also can run the MySQL command `show processlist` to see what queries are being processed at that time.

Also have a look into all other application specific error logs.

A first try could be to disable foreign key checks during migration:
`SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

A first guess would be, that the old server supported 0 as Primary Key values, whilst the new one does not.